# Using two XSLT key() functions in combination

Tags: xml, xslt, key

I want to ask you if there is a better way to transform the xml or to build the XML. Maybe to understand the topic...
I want to create a table which shows the name of the person, its zodiac and the movie genres based of the zodiac of each person.

```
<data>       <!-- Added root element by edit -->
    <persons>
        <person>
            <name>Nora Martin </name>
            <zodiac zid="9"/>
        </person>
        <person>
            <name>Andy Fürst </name>
            <zodiac zid="7"/>
        </person>
        <person>
            <name>Daniel Zweifel</name>
            <zodiac zid="3"/>
        </person>
        <person>
            <name>Daniela Hagen</name>
            <zodiac zid="5"/>
        </person>
        <person>
            <name>Sabine Meier</name>
            <zodiac zid="2"/>
        </person>
        <person>
            <name>Sarah-Corina Ehrsam</name>
            <zodiac zid="11"/>
        </person>
        <person>
            <name>Claudia Martin</name>
            <zodiac zid="10"/>
        </person>
        <person>
            <name>Tobias Martin</name>
            <zodiac zid="12"/>
        </person>
        <person>
            <name>Heidi Klum</name>
            <zodiac zid="1"/>
        </person>
        <person>
            <name>Nadja Heer</name>
            <zodiac zid="8"/>
        </person>
        <person>
            <name>Timo Meier</name>
            <zodiac zid="4"/>
        </person>
        <person>
            <name>Pascal Ehrensperger</name>
            <zodiac zid="6"/>
        </person>
    </persons>
    <sternzeichen>
        <zeichen id="1">
            <name>Wassermann</name>
        </zeichen>
        <zeichen id="2">
            <name>Löwe</name>
        </zeichen>
        <zeichen id="3">
            <name>Steinbock</name>
        </zeichen>
        <zeichen id="4">
            <name>Zwilling</name>
        </zeichen>
        <zeichen id="5">
            <name>Krebs</name>
        </zeichen>
        <zeichen id="6">
            <name>Jungfrau</name>
        </zeichen>
        <zeichen id="7">
            <name>Fisch</name>
        </zeichen>
        <zeichen id="8">
            <name>Skorpion</name>
        </zeichen>
        <zeichen id="9">
            <name>Waage</name>
        </zeichen>
        <zeichen id="10">
            <name>Schütze</name>
        </zeichen>
        <zeichen id="11">
            <name>Widder</name>
        </zeichen>
        <zeichen id="12">
            <name>Stier</name>
        </zeichen>
    </sternzeichen>
    <record>
        <Genre>Documentary</Genre>
        <preferredzodiacs>
            <preference signId="1" />
            <preference signId="2" />
        </preferredzodiacs>
    </record>
    <record>
        <Genre>Drama|Film-Noir|Thriller</Genre>
        <preferredzodiacs>
            <preference signId="3" />
            <preference signId="2" />
        </preferredzodiacs>
    </record>
    <record>
        <Genre>Drama</Genre>
        <preferredzodiacs>
            <preference signId="10" />
            <preference signId="12" />
            <preference signId="11" />
        </preferredzodiacs>
    </record>
    <record>
        <Genre>Comedy</Genre>
        <preferredzodiacs>
            <preference signId="1" />
            <preference signId="2" />
            <preference signId="3" />
            <preference signId="4" />
            <preference signId="5" />
            <preference signId="6" />
        </preferredzodiacs>
    </record>
    <record>
        <Genre>Comedy|Romance</Genre>
        <preferredzodiacs>
            <preference signId="10" />
            <preference signId="9" />
            <preference signId="1" />
        </preferredzodiacs>
    </record>
    <record>
        <Genre>Drama|Mystery|Thriller</Genre>
        <preferredzodiacs>
            <preference signId="4" />
            <preference signId="5" />
        </preferredzodiacs>
    </record>
    <record>
        <Genre>Crime|Drama</Genre>
        <preferredzodiacs>
            <preference signId="7" />
            <preference signId="5" />
        </preferredzodiacs>
    </record>
    <record>
        <Genre>Drama|Film-Noir</Genre>
        <preferredzodiacs>
            <preference signId="8" />
            <preference signId="9" />
        </preferredzodiacs>
    </record>
    <record>
        <Genre>Crime|Drama</Genre>
        <preferredzodiacs>
            <preference signId="2" />
            <preference signId="7" />
        </preferredzodiacs>
    </record>
    <record>
        <Genre>Adventure|Children|Fantasy</Genre>
        <preferredzodiacs>
            <preference signId="6" />
            <preference signId="10" />
        </preferredzodiacs>
    </record>
    <record>
        <Genre>Fantasy|Musical|Mystery</Genre>
        <preferredzodiacs>
            <preference signId="1" />
            <preference signId="12" />
        </preferredzodiacs>
    </record>
    <record>
        <Genre>Crime|Drama|Thriller</Genre>
        <preferredzodiacs>
            <preference signId="7" />
            <preference signId="9" />
        </preferredzodiacs>
    </record>
    <record>
        <Genre>Horror</Genre>
        <preferredzodiacs>
            <preference signId="12" />
            <preference signId="1" />
        </preferredzodiacs>
    </record>
    <record>
        <Genre>Crime|Drama|Mystery</Genre>
        <preferredzodiacs>
            <preference signId="8" />
            <preference signId="5" />
        </preferredzodiacs>
    </record>
    <record>
        <Genre>Western</Genre>
        <preferredzodiacs>
            <preference signId="3" />
            <preference signId="9" />
        </preferredzodiacs>
    </record>
    <record>
        <Genre>Horror|Sci-Fi|Thriller</Genre>
        <preferredzodiacs>
            <preference signId="4" />
            <preference signId="5" />
            <preference signId="8" />
        </preferredzodiacs>
    </record>
    <record>
        <Genre>Drama|Thriller</Genre>
        <preferredzodiacs>
            <preference signId="7" />
            <preference signId="4" />
            <preference signId="2" />
        </preferredzodiacs>
    </record>
    <record>
        <Genre>Action|Crime|Thriller</Genre>
        <preferredzodiacs>
            <preference signId="3" />
            <preference signId="6" />
            <preference signId="7" />
        </preferredzodiacs>
    </record>
    <record>
        <Genre>Drama|Horror</Genre>
        <preferredzodiacs>
            <preference signId="9" />
            <preference signId="10" />
            <preference signId="8" />
        </preferredzodiacs>
    </record>
    <record>
        <Genre>Comedy|Drama</Genre>
        <preferredzodiacs>
            <preference signId="1" />
            <preference signId="2" />
            <preference signId="8" />
        </preferredzodiacs>
    </record>
    <record>
        <Genre>Drama|Thriller</Genre>
        <preferredzodiacs>
            <preference signId="12" />
            <preference signId="11" />
            <preference signId="5" />
        </preferredzodiacs>
    </record>
    <record>
        <Genre>Sci-Fi</Genre>
        <preferredzodiacs>
            <preference signId="6" />
            <preference signId="10" />
        </preferredzodiacs>
    </record>
    <record>
        <Genre>Crime|Drama|Thriller</Genre>
        <preferredzodiacs>
            <preference signId="5" />
            <preference signId="1" />
        </preferredzodiacs>
    </record>
    <record>
        <Genre>Action</Genre>
        <preferredzodiacs>
            <preference signId="1" />
        </preferredzodiacs>
    </record>
    <record>
        <Genre>Comedy|Romance</Genre>
        <preferredzodiacs>
            <preference signId="11" />
            <preference signId="8" />
        </preferredzodiacs>
    </record>
    <record>
        <Genre>Action|Drama|Mystery</Genre>
        <preferredzodiacs>
            <preference signId="9" />
            <preference signId="11" />
        </preferredzodiacs>
    </record>
    <record>
        <Genre>Romance|Thriller</Genre>
        <preferredzodiacs>
            <preference signId="5" />
            <preference signId="7" />
        </preferredzodiacs>
    </record>
</data>
```

and the XSLT-1.0 code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:key name="SternzeichenID" match="zeichen" use="@id"/>
    <xsl:key name="GenreZodiac" match="preference" use="@signId"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <head>
                <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous" />
                <!-- Added closing '/' with edit -->
                <title>Movie Dating</title>
                <body>
                    <table class="table table-striped">
                        <tr>
                            <th>Person</th>
                            <th>Sternzeichen</th>
                            <th>passende Filme</th>
                        </tr>
                        <xsl:for-each select="data/persons/person">
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="name"/>
                                </td>
                                <!--Name der person in persons/person ausgeben-->
                                <xsl:for-each select= "key('SternzeichenID', zodiac/@zid)" >
                                    <td>
                                        <xsl:value-of select= "name"/>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <ul>
                                            <xsl:for-each select="key('GenreZodiac',@id)">
                                                <li>
                                                    <xsl:value-of select= "../../Genre"/>
                                                </li>
                                            </xsl:for-each>
                                        </ul>
                                    </td>
                                </xsl:for-each>
                            </tr>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                    </table>
                </body>
            </head>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This is some XSL fragment:

```
          <xsl:for-each select="data/persons/person">
            <tr>
              <td><xsl:value-of select="name"/></td>     <!--Name der person in persons/person ausgeben-->
              <xsl:for-each select= "key('SternzeichenID', zodiac/@zid)" >
              <td><xsl:value-of select= "name"/></td>
                <td>
                <ul>
                  <xsl:for-each select="key('GenreZodiac',@id)">
                          <li>
                          <xsl:value-of select= "../../Genre"/>
```

My problem is that I have some difficulties to understand the `xsl:for-each` select and the value of select functions.

Could you please explain to me what each function does and what the result of the function is.
Please do it step by step because I'm a newbie.

1. i know the first one gives the persons name
2. shows the zodiac of the person
3. shows the favourite film genres

is there a better and easier way to do it?

Comment: Your XSLT and XML had some errors, so I edited it to fix these problems. But the code is working well. Add the line `<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="yourXSLTname.xslt" ?>` right after the `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>` of your XML file. Then you can see the immediate result in the browser by opening the XML file in it (unless you have the latest versions which block this).

Comment: Relating to your question: this approach is probably close to the optimum.

Comment: thank you. could you help me to explain the goal of each "for each" and "value of select". i received the code from a friend of mine and i have problem to understand its purpose:  especially   <xsl:for-each select= "key('SternzeichenID', zodiac/@zid)" >
              <td><xsl:value-of select= "name"/></td>      and     xsl:for-each select="key('GenreZodiac',@id)">
                          <li>
                          <xsl:value-of select= "../../Genre"/>

Comment: maybe you coul explain it to me? what it does ? what it receives and so on. and why i have to use 2 xsl.keys.. thank you

Comment: Is there anyone that can briefly explain whats happening in these functions or-each loop?

Comment: ah sorry. thank you very very much

Answer (score 0):

The line

```
<xsl:for-each select= "key('SternzeichenID', zodiac/@zid)" >
```

loops over all `key` entries of the 'SternzeichenID' `xsl:key` which match the key value `zodiac/@zid` attribute. So, for example, the line

```
<xsl:for-each select="data/persons/person">
```

sets the context node to the `person` element. The first one is

```
<person>
  <name>Nora Martin </name>
  <zodiac zid="9"/>
</person>
```

Now, the attribute value of `zodiac/@zid` can be retrieved - which has a value of `9`. This value, `9` is used as an input to the `xsl:key` named 'SternzeichenID' with

```
key('SternzeichenID', zodiac/@zid)
```

Its result are all `zeichen` elements which have an `id` attribute which equals `zodiac/@zid` - with the value of `9`. The `xsl:for-each` iterates over this result. The current item is called the `current()` node and is a `zeichen` element.

Now, the line

```
<xsl:for-each select="key('GenreZodiac',@id)">
```

retrieves the values from the `xsl:key` named 'GenreZodiac'. The key is `current()/@id` = `zeichen/@id` = `9`. Its result is a nodeset of all "preference" elements which `@signId` attributes are equal to the `zeichen/@id` attribute.

Now, the `xsl:for-each` iterates over all of these `preference` elements and then outputs the values of the `Genre` ancestor elements - which are located at `../../` - meaning they are two `ancestor::` axis levels above.

In this case, the "Waage" nodeset consists of the following `<Genre>` elements:

- Comedy|Romance
- Drama|Film-Noir
- Crime|Drama|Thriller
- Western
- Drama|Horror
- Action|Drama|Mystery

I hope this helps you understand `xsl:key`s and `xsl:for-each`s.

Comment: thank you so much. and the last question: could you explain the keys itself to me?   <xsl:key name="SternzeichenID" match="zeichen" use="@id"/>
    <xsl:key name="GenreZodiac" match="preference" use="@signId"/>   thank you so much

Comment: "SternzeichenID" matches globally all `<zeichen>` elements and _uses_ their `@id` attributes as key values. The other key functions analogous.